# How to have 2 fixed footers at the bottom of a page

Tags: javascript, css

I have an issue where I'm wanting to add a fixed bar at the bottom of a page. My issue arises when there is already a fixed bar at the bottom of the page. Is there any way with CSS and JavaScript to have my bar be placed at the very bottom and "push up" the previous bar to stack above it?

Comment: Add `position: relative;` to parent element. Look at [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/dHD5A/)

Comment: How does your current HTML and CSS look like? It's difficult to answer without concrete code.

Comment: @Givi is there a way if you don't know where the original bar is located? The reason I ask is my bar is just a drop-in bar to any website.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to nest those 2 elements in an other `div` and to give fixed positioning to the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This code searches for an existing footer (assuming fixed positioning and bottom 0).

If found, it makes it the first child of your footer (class `myFooter`).

It also changes the original footer to static positioning.

```
var obj = document.querySelectorAll('*'),
    myFooter= document.querySelector('.myFooter'),
    i,
    cs;

for(i = 0 ; i < obj.length ; i++) {
  cs= getComputedStyle(obj[i]);
  if(obj[i] !== myFooter &&
     cs.getPropertyValue('position')==='fixed' &&
     parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('bottom'))===0
    ) {
    myFooter.insertBefore(obj[i],myFooter.firstChild);
    obj[i].style.position= 'static';
  }
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrfwyu2g/)